# Order list of tupples by string date year/month

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples

I have this list of tuples, that I need to order by year/month.

From `2016/7`, `2016/8`, `2016/9`, `2016/10`, `2016/11` ... to the last year/month, in this case `2017/10`

```
visits_count = [
('2017/9', 6175L), 
('2017/8', 13522L), 
('2016/10', 264L), 
('2016/11', 227L), 
('2016/7', 1519L), 
('2017/1', 496L), 
('2016/9', 726L), 
('2017/3', 404L), 
('2017/2', 253L), 
('2017/5', 601L), 
('2017/4', 151L), 
('2017/7', 14300L), 
('2017/6', 192L), 
('2016/8', 2293L), 
('2016/12', 28L), 
('2017/10', 1333L)
]
```

I already tried  `print sorted(visits_count.items())` but the output is not what I am expecting. Any idea how to achieve that output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a `dict`, so it has no items. Sorting it just like that will sort it lexicographically (e.g. month `'10'` before `'2'`). Hence, you have to provide an appropriate key function that evaluates years and months as numbers and not strings:

```
# Py2
>>> sorted(visits_count, key=lambda tpl: map(int, tpl[0].split('/')))
# Py3
>>> sorted(visits_count, key=lambda tpl: list(map(int, tpl[0].split('/'))))
[('2016/7', 1519),
 ('2016/8', 2293),
 ('2016/9', 726),
 ('2016/10', 264),
 ('2016/11', 227),
 ('2016/12', 28),
 ('2017/1', 496),
 ('2017/2', 253),
 ('2017/3', 404),
 ('2017/4', 151),
 ('2017/5', 601),
 ('2017/6', 192),
 ('2017/7', 14300),
 ('2017/8', 13522),
 ('2017/9', 6175),
 ('2017/10', 1333)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `key` argument:

```
sorted(visits_count, key=lambda x: tuple(int(y) for y in x[0].split('/')))
```

Alternatively, if the `lambda` is to dense, write a dedicated function:

```
def make_date_tuple(value):
    return tuple(int(x) for x in value[0].split('/'))

sorted(visits_count, key=make_date_tuple)

Result:

[('2016/7', 1519),
 ('2016/8', 2293),
 ('2016/9', 726),
 ('2016/10', 264),
 ('2016/11', 227),
 ('2016/12', 28),
 ('2017/1', 496),
 ('2017/2', 253),
 ('2017/3', 404),
 ('2017/4', 151),
 ('2017/5', 601),
 ('2017/6', 19),
 ('2017/7', 14300),
 ('2017/8', 13522),
 ('2017/9', 6175),
 ('2017/10', 1333)]
```

The return value of `make_date_tuple()` is used for sorting.
You need to convert the string into two integers, using the year as first and the month as a second entry of a tuple such as `(2016, 7)`.
This results into sorting, first by year and second my month.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the highest performance you could use the failsafe datetime library.

```
import datetime

visits_count = [
('2017/9', 6175), 
('2017/8', 13522), 
('2016/10', 264), 
('2016/11', 227), 
('2016/7', 1519), 
('2017/1', 496), 
('2016/9', 726), 
('2017/3', 404), 
('2017/2', 253), 
('2017/5', 601), 
('2017/4', 151), 
('2017/7', 14300), 
('2017/6', 192), 
('2016/8', 2293), 
('2016/12', 28), 
('2017/10', 1333)
]

sorted(visits_count,key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0],"%Y/%m"))
```